# Splitting a line of String

Tags: java

If have a String line `AND A B C -> D` passed into the method `public void parseComponentLine(String line)`, I need to check if A B C D are inside my `innerWires`(I do not need to worry about it though for now). I just need to know how to extract only `A B C D` in the method by ignoring `AND` and `->` inside `parseComponentLine(String line)`?? Note: the input String can be anything similar.

```
public void parseComponentLine(String line) throws IOException
    {
        String[] array = line.split("->");
}
```

Comment: `String[] array = line.substring(4).split(" | -> ");`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the contains method, this code:

```
String example = "AND A B C -> D ";
System.out.println(example.contains(" A "));
System.out.println(example.contains(" E "));
```

Would print:

> true
>   false

If you know A, B, C and D beforehand

Comment: Not a bad answer, doesn't quite "Split" it, but as you said this would work with "if(example.contains(" A ") && example.contains(" B ") && ...).  Horrible code, but seems like it would solve this guy's problem--don't know why you got a downvote but I fixed it.